# Como acessar o host local a partir de um container Docker?

Tags: sql-server, docker

Estou começando agora com Docker e estou perdido em um pequeno detalhe, montei um imagem Ubuntu com Apache, PHP 7 e a extensão de conexão com SQL Server.

Como faço para acessar o servidor do SQL Server se ele está na minha rede local e o Docker a rede está apenas na minha maquina?

Exemplo:

> IP do container = 172.18.0.2
>
> IP do meu SQL Server = 192.168.0.58

Lembrando que uso o Docker no windows 10.

Caso de para acessar tenho já como colocar essa informação ou no meu Dockerfile ou no docker-compose?

Comment: Votei para reabrir essa pergunta por considerar o Docker uma "ferramentas comuns entre programadores", o que a torna dentro do escopo definido na central de ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem duas formas de você fazer isso.

Uma é você executar o SQL Server a partir de um container. É possível executar ele a partir de um container Linux inclusive:

[Quickstart: Run the SQL Server 2017 container image with Docker](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker)

A configuração no seu docker-compose.yml ficará parecido com isso:

```
version: "3.4"

services:

  ubuntu:
    build: .

  mssql-linux:
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=MySafePassw0rd!
    volumes:
      - mssql-data:/var/opt/mssql/data

volumes:
  mssql-data:
    driver: local
```

A vantagem de fazer dessa forma é que fica mais fácil para quem não tem o SQL Server instalado na maquina executar algo.

A segunda forma é alterarando o network no Docker Compose para ao invés de executar dentro do NAT usar a mesma rede do host

```
version: "3.4"

services:

  ubuntu:
    build: .

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: host
```

Ou também usar a option `--net=host` ao rodar o container

```
docker container run --net=host minha-imagem
```